# Using logical operators in lighttpd.conf

Tags: lighttpd

I have two sub-domains which I want to redirect to the same directory:

```
$HTTP["host"] =~ "sub1\.example\.com$" {
    server.document-root = "/home/adam/html/sub_domain" 
}

$HTTP["host"] =~ "sub2\.example\.com$" {
    server.document-root = "/home/adam/html/sub_domain" 
}
```

Naturally, I've tried:

```
$HTTP["host"] =~ "sub1\.example\.com$" OR $HTTP["host"] =~ "sub2\.example\.com$"{
    server.document-root = "/home/adam/html/sub_domain" 
}
```

But got:

```
2011-03-14 10:19:30: (configfile.c.855) source: /etc/lighttpd/lighttpd.conf 
    line: 199 pos: 36 parser failed somehow near here: or
```

This failed with `OR` (upper case), `or` and even c-style `||`.

Any idea how to avoid the awkward code repetition?

This question is a copy of an [unanswered post I've published](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/boards/2/topics/4182) in the lighttpd forum.

Answer (score 3):

Why not just...?

```
$HTTP["host"] =~ "^sub(1|2)\.example\.com$" {
    server.document-root = "/home/adam/html/sub_domain" 
}
```

Comment: Note: This method does not work with `$SERVER["socket"]`.

Answer (score 1):

Alicia's answer is probably the best for this question, but if someone stumbles upon this for whom a regex fix doesn't work – like I did before – I want to quickly share which solution worked for me:

> Lighttpd has no AND / OR logical operators, but it's possible to obtain the same behavior by nesting / chaining conditions.
>
> **Logical AND:**
>
> ```
> condition1 {
>     condition2 {
>         doSomething
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> → nested if blocks are equivalent to a logical AND
>
> **Logical OR:**
>
> ```
> condition1 {
>     doSomething
> }
> condition2 {
>     doSomething
> }
> ```
>
> → chained if blocks are equivalent to a logical OR
>
> **if-then-elif-else construct:**
>
> ```
> condition1 {
>     doSomething1  ← then block
> }
> else condition2 {
>     doSomething2  ← else if block
> }
> else {
>     doSomething3  ← else block
> }
> ```

Taken from: https://doc.callmematthi.eu/lighttpd.html

Comment: I'd add an `else` in the "logical OR" case too, else if both conditions are true it would "do something" twice.

Answer (score 0):

Try -o for logical OR.
Try -a for logical AND.

Also reference [this page](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-basic-operators.htm) for some more operator commands in *nix.

report back and let us know if that works!

Comment: Does not work: `2011-03-14 14:04:05: (configfile.c.855) source: lighttpd.conf line: 200 pos: 36 parser failed somehow near here: -o`